# jpa select statement with subnets

Tags: java, sql, jpa-2.0

I am trying to write query with multiple select subnets in it.But I defined a nativequery 
 I am giving error. Compiler specifies that "**(**" after "**from**" is not proper. How can I define 
a native query in JPA 2.0
For eaxmple:

```
SELECT *
from (SELECT ****C) REI3 where column1 != 1 
GROUP BY REI3.column2  order by REI3.column3 ASC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JPA does not have too much to do with validating SQL syntax, query is passed to JDBC driver. Likely you are trying run query such a way, that it is interpreted as JP QL.  Instead try  following method to execute it as

```
Query q = em.createNativeQuery("Your SQL here");
```

Other alternative is to use [NamedNativeQuery](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/NamedNativeQuery.html) [Example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JPA/UsingNamedNativeQuery.htm)